# Remove "delete product" option for user role

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, admin, user-roles

I have a custom user in my magento store backend.
I want to restrict him from deleting any products, just add/edit what is already there.

Comment: Check  https://github.com/sohelrana09/sr-module-trashcan

Comment: @Sohel This looks ok. I will try as last option if all else fails!!! Thanks.